# wordpress local host web login not working after port configuration

Tags: localhost, local-installation

I installed the word press on my vm and configure my port 8000.
Now, when I am trying to login into wordpress 
using

```
  http://localhost:8000/wordpress/
```

on browser , the link is getting changing into

```
  http://localhost/wordpress/
```

and displaying "Problem loading page : Unable to connect". I have checked xampp and I am able to access it

```
  http://localhost:8000/xampp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the 'siteurl' and 'home' values in your wp_options table, and update those URLs to:

`http://localhost:8000/wordpress`